# First n elements of a list (Tail-Recursive)

Tags: scheme, racket

After figuring out the recursive version of this algorithm, I'm attempting to create an iterative (tail-recursive) version.

I'm quite close, but the list that is returned ends up being reversed.

Here is what I have so far:

```
(define (first-n-iter lst n)
  (define (iter lst lst-proc x)
    (cond
      ((= x 0) lst-proc)
      (else (iter (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) lst-proc) (- x 1)))))
  (if (= n 0)
      '()
      (iter lst '() n)))
```

i.e. Calling `(first-n-iter '(a b c) 3)` will return `(c b a)`.

Could someone suggest a fix? Once again, I'd like to retain the tail-recursion.

*note:* I'd prefer you not suggest just calling `(reverse lst)` on the returned list..

Comment: But, calling reverse on the result _is_ the standard way to implement this.

Comment: Is it really? I wasn't aware of that. I was hoping I could implement it with just the use of `cons` `car` and `cdr`, but if that is really the case then I'll just have to live with it.

Comment: It really is. Since `reverse` is used in this way, many implementation provide very fast builtin versions of `reverse`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the head sentinel trick to implement a tail recursive modulo cons

```
(define (first-n-iter lst n)
  (define result (cons 'head '()))
  (define (iter tail L-ns x)
    (cond
      ((= x 0) (cdr result))
      ((null? L-ns) 
       (error "FIRST-N-ITER input list " lst " less than N" n))
      (else 
       (begin (set-cdr! tail (list (car L-ns)))
              (iter (cdr tail) (cdr L-ns) (- x 1))))))
      (iter result lst n))


(first-n-iter '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) 8))

;Value 7: (a b c d e f g h)
```

Also added a cond clause to catch the case where you try to take more elements than are actually present in the list.

Comment: This works in regular Scheme, but it doesn't work in Racket, where `set-cdr!` doesn't exist because lists are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You could flip the arguments for your `cons` statement, `list` the last (previously first) arg, and change the `cons` to `append`

```
(define (first-n-iter lst n)
  (define (iter lst acc x)
    (cond
      [(zero? x) acc]
      [else (iter (cdr lst) (append acc (list (car lst))) (sub1 x))]))
  (iter lst empty n))
```

which will work as you wanted. And if you're doing this as a learning exercise, then I think that's all you need. But if you're actually trying to make this function, you should know that it's been done already-- `(take lst 3)`

Also, you don't need your `if` statement at all-- your check for `(= x 0)` would return `'()` right away, and you pass in `(iter lst '() n)` as it is. So the `(if (= n 0) ... )` is doing work that `(cond [(= x 0)...)`' would already do for you.